# Inverse Laplace transform of $e^{-s^{1/2}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> Inverse Laplace transform of $e^{-s^{1/2}}$

I tried solving this question using the series expansion of $e^x$. However, I cant seem to proceed ahead with the inverse transform

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2153928/inverse-laplace-transform-of-e-sqrt-s

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the fact that for $a>0$, the inverse transform of $e^{-\sqrt{ap}}$ is $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}x^{-3/2}e^{-\frac{a}{4x}}$. Please vote if you find this helpful.